# Need to replace href of anchor tags in a string

Tags: c#, regex

```
string content=" 
        <br /><br /><a href="need to replace this url">Cooking School</a><br /><br /><a href="http://www.sdlm.com">Feed your senses</a><br /><br /><a href="http://www.sdl.com">Take your cooking skills to the next level. Find a cooking school near you!</a><br /><br /><a href="http:google.com"><img src="http://www.sdlm1.com/autd3umrl_u_t.jpg" /></a>
     "
```

I need to replace all anchor tags href value with different urls
I used the following function but its getting error

```
 public List<string> GetLinksFromHtml(string content)
        {
            string regex = @"<(?<Tag_Name>(a)|img)\b[^>]*?\b(?<URL_Type>(?(1)href|src))\s*=\s*(?:""(?<URL>(?:\\""|[^""])*)""|'(?<URL>(?:\\'|[^'])*)'))";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(content, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            var links = new List<string>();

            foreach (Match item in matches)
            {
                string link = item.Groups[1].Value;
                links.Add(link);
            }

            return links;
        }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I just want to get all anchor tag href values so that i can replace them with other urls which i want. when i search in stack overflow i got above function and i just tried but error is --> parsing "<(?<Tag_Name>(a)|img)\b[^>]*?\b(?<URL_Type>(?(1)href|src))\s*=\s*(?:"(?<URL>(?:\\"|[^"])*)"|'(?<URL>(?:\\'|[^'])*)'))" - Too many )'s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to parse html with regex is not a good idea. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) .

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(content);
foreach (var a in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a"))
{
    a.Attributes["href"].Value = "http://a.com?url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(a.Attributes["href"].Value);
}

var newContent = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: iam not getting HtmlAgilityPack dll

Comment: @user1622436 What does it mean? "you can't" or "you don't want"

Comment: What is so hard? Go to link in answer. Click Download and Unzip the file :)

Comment: ya i have done that. but in each folder there is a dll. so which dll i need to take pls tell me

Comment: @user1622436 Foldernames says the .net version(sl for silverlight). Choose whatever is appropriate for you.