# Replace href in string but conditionally using C#

Tags: c#, replace, href

I have a string (basically HTML code in string) and have to replace "href" tags within it. But there is one condition that if it is like "href=mailto:...." then it should not be replaced.
If I use string.Replace(), it replaces all the occurrences.
Can someone suggest if I can achieve this without affecting the performance.

P.S. One solution could be to take all href elements in array with their indexes, but that too clumsy and time consuming.

Comment: Add an if-clause to the answer provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912632/need-to-replace-href-of-anchor-tags-in-a-string.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it in three steps

```
replace "href=mailto" => "A8316F2B-96BD-44A9-BD90-4C8F7DF4152B"
replace href ....
replace "A8316F2B-96BD-44A9-BD90-4C8F7DF4152B" => "href=mailto"
```

But i guess this makes it three times as slow. But does it matter? How big is the document and how often is it run?