# Manipulating an HTML file results in incorrect String indexes

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webclient

I am trying to manipulate an HTML file that I'm downloading using `WebClient`. I am using `Regex` to extract the values of the `href` attribute. Here is my code:

```
string html = "";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

html = webClient.DownloadString(addressTextBox.Text).Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", "");
 address = webClient.BaseAddress;

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(html);
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(html, @"(?<=\bhref="")[^""]*");

int offset = 0;

foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
{
    string newValue = addressTextBox.Text + match.Value.Replace("./", "").Replace("../", "");
    int tempOffset = match.Index - offset;

    stringBuilder.Remove(tempOffset, match.Length);
    stringBuilder.Insert(tempOffset, newValue);
    offset = newValue.Length - match.Length;
}

webBrowser.DocumentText = stringBuilder.ToString();
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\site.xml", stringBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. I am trying to get the index of where the value of an `href` attribute is
2. I am trying to remove the attribute's value
3. I am inserting a new value to replace the old one
4. Since the new attribute value is generally larger than the old one, I have created an `offset` variable to store the difference between the previous attribute value's length and the new one. Then, I am subtracting the offset from the next match's index

Below is a screenshot of the damage that occurs after I try to manipulate the web page:

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly replace the values of each `href` attribute?

Comment: Trying to manipulate HTML via regexes is about the most difficult and error-prone way possible. Use HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Here is very good highly up-voted explanation what you are doing wrong - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/... More info on HAP - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack (in addition to explanation how to do what you just asked which is reasonable duplicate from my point of view - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912632/need-to-replace-href-of-anchor-tags-in-a-string)

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will try to use HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Thanks Alexei for sharing those posts. They were really helpful.